# SQL Query select, execution timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 the following select works in 3 seconds with IN and 20 minutes with NOT IN. Doing the same select on SQL Server 2012 takes 3 seconds for both IN and NOT IN. Has anyone had this occur before and if so is there a different query that would reduce this latency?

Background: total MessageIndentifier records is ~9000. `IN` returns ~1400, `NOT IN` returns ~7600. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
SELECT 
    AA.[MessageIdentifier]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         CAST(AD.[Contract Number] AS VARCHAR) + '.' + 
            CAST(AD.[Installation ID] AS VARCHAR) + '.'+ 
            CAST(AD.[System ID] AS VARCHAR) AS MessageIdentifier
     FROM 
         CDCS_FAMS.dbo.SiteParamBaseTable AD) AS AA
WHERE 
    AA.[MessageIdentifier] IN (SELECT DISTINCT AB.[MessageIdentifier]
                               FROM 
                                   (SELECT cast(AC.[Contract Number] as varchar) + '.' + cast(AC.[Installation ID] as varchar) + '.'+ cast(AC.[System ID] as varchar) AS MessageIdentifier
                                    FROM CDCS_FAMS.dbo.SiteParamBaseTable AC) AS AB,
                                   CDCS_FAMS.dbo.EventTable as DA
                               WHERE 
                                  (DA.[Message] LIKE '%ISO MODE:%' 
                                   OR DA.[Message] LIKE '%TEST MODE:%') 
                                  AND DA.[Message] LIKE '%Alarm%' 
                                  AND DA.[Event time] > DATEADD(DAY,-10, GETDATE())
                                  AND DA.[Message] LIKE '%' + AB.[MessageIdentifier] + '%')
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use exists instead of IN/Not In

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your execution time out by `sp_configure`.

for more information you can [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. your second query

   ```
   SELECT 
       cast(AC.[Contract Number] as varchar) + '.' + cast(AC.[Installation ID] as varchar) + '.'+ cast(AC.[System ID] as varchar) AS MessageIdentifier
   FROM 
       CDCS_FAMS.dbo.SiteParamBaseTable AC
   ```

   is excess
2. use `exists` or `not exists` in your main where, in my example I use `exists` but you can change it to `not exists`, this will be more faster than  your query, try it

Code:

```
SELECT AA.[MessageIdentifier]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         cast(AD.[Contract Number] as varchar) + '.' + cast(AD.[Installation ID] as varchar) + '.'+ cast(AD.[System ID] as varchar) AS MessageIdentifier
     FROM 
         CDCS_FAMS.dbo.SiteParamBaseTable AD) AS AA
     WHERE 
         EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM CDCS_FAMS.dbo.EventTable as DA
                 WHERE (DA.[Message] like '%ISO MODE:%' or DA.[Message] like '%TEST MODE:%') 
                   AND DA.[Message] like '%Alarm%' 
                   AND DA.[Event time] > DATEADD(DAY,-10,GETDATE())
                   AND DA.[Message] like '%'+AA.[MessageIdentifier]+'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, much appreciated. Have sorted.
I was not correctly accounting for NULLs in the NOT IN condition. Using the NOT IN with SQL2012 is ok but doesn't work the same in SQL2008R2.
To fix I did a LEFT JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ... IS NULL.
This did the trick.

Thanks for the responses again.

BMV